# Chart Area with scrollbar

Tags: c#, forms, charts, scrollbar

I would like to have on the six chartareas on the image 6 scrollbars i have genrate it but on the srollbar apears a button if i pressed the button the scrollbare hide  but i do not want this button can anyone help me with this Problem please.

the unintentional Button[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWnV8.png)

```
    private void makeChartsScrollable(Chart chart) {

            chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
        // chart.ChartAreas[3].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = false;
        // chart.ChartAreas[3].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = false;
        // chart.ChartAreas[2].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
        // chart.ChartAreas[2].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = true;
        // chart.ChartAreas[2].AxisX.ScaleView.Position = 0;
        // chart.ChartAreas[2].AxisX.ScaleView.Size = 23;


        //chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX.
        chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(0, 8);
        chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX.ScaleView.MinSize = 0;
        chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
        chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX.ScrollBar.Size = 23;
        chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = Color.Silver;
        chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX.ScrollBar.LineColor = Color.Black;


        /*
        chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX2.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
        chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX2.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
        chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX2.ScaleView.Position = 0;
        chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX2.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
        chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX2.ScaleView.Size = 23;
        chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX2.ScrollBar.ButtonColor = Color.Silver;
        chart.ChartAreas[3].AxisX2.ScrollBar.LineColor = Color.Black;*/

    }
```

Comment: Remove the ButtonColor line.

Comment: The small button in the corner is there to reset the scroll/zoom state. If you remove it, make sure to supply the users with a replacement. To remove simply chose a suitable `.ScrollBar.ButtonStyle = ScrollBarButtonStyles...`